# How to remove + and - signs from string immediate after coming after or before any character only not from other places in python3

Tags: python-3.x

From following input string

```
INPUT => --- text1 +++ text2 @@ -71,0 +72,4 @@ +t+o+o+l
OUTPUT => --- text1 +++ text2 @@ -71,0 +72,4 @@ tool
```

How can I remove + and - signs from string?

Comment: I have give input string and expected output string in the description

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

This code will replace either a + or - immediately before or after a letter (lower or upper case). It may be possible with only a single regex but I couldn't figure it out!

```
import re

line = re.sub(r"[\+-]([a-zA-Z])", "\g<1>", string)
line = re.sub(r"([a-zA-Z])[\+-]", "\g<1>", line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
import re
s = input()
s = re.sub(r"[\+-]([a-zA-Z])", "\g<1>", s)
s = re.sub(r"([a-zA-Z])[\+-]", "\g<1>", s)
print(s)
```

This will remove + and - signs.